# Cannot add top constraint to a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to add a constraint to an image view and a superview this way:

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
  item: self.image, 
  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 
  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
  toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, 
  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 
  multiplier: 1, 
  constant: 200)
image.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```

When I run my app it crashes with this output:

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the constraint to `self.view` instead of `self.image`:

```
self.view.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```

`self.topLayoutGuide` is a child element of `self.view`, not `self.image`. And as the error said, referencing in a constraint something from outside the subtree of the view installing the constraint is illegal.

In other words, `self.image` and `self.topLayoutGuide` are siblings in the view hierarchy, and you must add the constraint to the "father" of these siblings (`self.view`).

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in an Interface Builder (StoryBoard) solution:

If top/bottom constraints are unable to add/edit as shown.
[image]

First, select the item you wish to add these constraints to in the "Navigate to Related Items" pane, then CTRL click it to a nearby item in the view and constrain its top/bottom to that item arbitrarily.

[image]
[image]

This creates a constraint you otherwise could not add, which you may now locate, and open the attributes inspector for to edit as you please; hence, the arbitrary initial choice.

[image]
[image]

Though this seems to only work if your view contains other items which you were able to constrain without issue, as adding this constraint will be dependent on at least one already existing.